# Deeplink when you are inside a Configurable Tab

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am using Microsoft Teams Toolkit to create a configurable tab. When I am in the configurable tab, I would like to save the Deeplink for this tab to one of my database. However what I see is the App id is changing for the app package I have. I generated the app package using the Teams toolkit and then I uploaded in two Teams Channel on different tenant. I see the app id is changed in both the link. How can I make sure that app id remain same. Also is there any way I can get app id  and Tab id dynamically in Tab itself?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is my code:

````
microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
      teamId = context.groupId;
      tenantid = context.tid;
      channelId = context.channelId;

      const entityId =
     "_djb2_msteams_prefix_" +
     Util.djb2_hash("<<AppId>>" + ":" + context.entityId.replace(/\+/g, " "));
     
      var ctx ;

     if (context.subEntityId ||  context.channelId) {
       ctx = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
         subEntityId: context.subEntityId,
         channelId: context.channelId
       }));
     };```

      //How to get the app id and the tab id
     linkUrl="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/**<<AppId>>**/"+entityId+"/" + "&context=" + ctx+ "&groupId="+context.groupId+"&tenantId="+context.tid;
});
 };


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5jGc.png
````

Comment: How are you deploying you app to both tenants? Are you not using the same app package (zip file)?

Comment: I am using the same app package zip file. But as this is a test, I am not deploying through Team Admin but go to the Team-> Click on + sign-> at the bottom Manage App -> Upload a custom app.

Comment: In that case, what do you mean " App id is changing for the app package I have"? If it's the same package, how is the app id changing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same app package, then the app id will be the same in both cases (it's the one defined in your manifest file inside the package), and the entity id will be the same in both tenants also for the same reason.

Comment: I am trying to create deeplink. When I grab the deeplink from my tenant it is like this:https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/ **914a9c82-462e-439a-911d-61e5176bacef** /_djb2_msteams_prefix_2042309305?context={"subEntityId":null,"channelId":"19:A6T5m3okl80Lw4SIctzkhyVG3x58SwSmNsWXiU0OVuA1@thread.tacv2"}&groupId=573e9025-8b85-4a34-85ae-90715f4e3bd28&tenantId=ae1e0a3b-7612-4f0a-8fa2-9cbb0c67b30d  .the id in the bold (**914a9c82-462e-439a-911d-61e5176bacef**) is changing as I change tenant. It is the app id even?

Comment: What do you mean "grab a deeplink"? Just create the deeplink directly yourself, like per the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links). It should be https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<your appId>/<whatever you defined as entityId for your tab>

Comment: I am able to get everything but just the app id. Its keep changing. HOw can I check the app id of the app. The app id in mNaifest.json, is not clearly what i see in the deeplink. : "manifestVersion": "1.9",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "<<appid>>",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",

Comment: What happens when you actually -use- that app id?

Comment: Deeplink doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue. Below is the way, you can get the app id in your configurable tab dynamically:

```
microsoftTeams.getTabInstances(function (tabInstances) {
        // alert(JSON.stringify(tabInstances));     
        var tab = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tabInstances.teamTabs.find(x => x.channelId ==channelId)));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tab));
        appid = tab["appId"];        
            
     });
```

Note: TabInstance doesnt have appId as a property, but when you stringly the object , you see the value.

Answer (score 0):

## Getting the App ID

When a customer in a tenant installs your App, this actually creates an instance of that app in their tenant.

If you, as a developer - installs or sideloads multiple copies of the same app in different scopes, this also creates new app-instance
Same for individual manifest uploads to a Team

This teams-app-instance is assigned an 'Internal App-ID'
you can see this in the Teams AppCatalog :
where the `externalid` is the `id` you specified in your App's `manifest.json`

In my personal experience you should be able to use the Teams_App_Manifest_id , but that you may/will into trouble when that resolves to more than one app-instance with that same external-id.
Note that links generated by the teams client tend to use the `internal id`. I assume to avoid that issue

### Getting the Tab ID

as in the Context you have the **Team.id** and **Channel.id** and your Tab's Entity.id  is, you then can use Graph to iterate across the tabs in that channel
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{groupId}/channels/{channelId}/tabs?$expand=teamsApp&$filter=configuration/entityId eq '{entityId}'`

**Tenant App Catalog:**
[graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=appCatalogs%2FteamsApps&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com)

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#appCatalogs/teamsApps",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "fcb9685a-8bc4-4b82-947b-12f8d2146ec3",
            "externalId": "73fb4e73-97e2-44f6-a880-160933ea881e",
            "displayName": "App SSO in csharp",
            "distributionMethod": "organization"
        },
```

**App install by user from tenant catalog (organization)**
[graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me%2Fteamwork%2FinstalledApps%3F%24expand%3DteamsApp&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com)

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('cb4d216f-1e86-4b8b-94f0-c213b258d376')/teamwork/installedApps(teamsApp())",
    "@odata.count": 86,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "Y2I0ZDIxNmYtMWU4Ni00YjhiLTk0ZjAtYzIxM2IyNThkMzc2IyNmY2I5Njg1YS04YmM0LTRiODItOTQ3Yi0xMmY4ZDIxNDZlYzM=",
            "teamsApp": {
                "id": "fcb9685a-8bc4-4b82-947b-12f8d2146ec3",
                "externalId": "73fb4e73-97e2-44f6-a880-160933ea881e",
                "displayName": "App SSO in csharp",
                "distributionMethod": "organization"
            }
        },
```

**adding the binary-same Teams app 'for me'**
results in the app showing twice in the left nav (as expected, so this also adds an App-instance with its own (internal) App id

[image]

```json
    "@odata.count": 87,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "Y2I0ZDIxNmYtMWU4Ni00YjhiLTk0ZjAtYzIxM2IyNThkMzc2IyNmY2I5Njg1YS04YmM0LTRiODItOTQ3Yi0xMmY4ZDIxNDZlYzM=",
            "teamsApp": {
                "id": "fcb9685a-8bc4-4b82-947b-12f8d2146ec3",
                "externalId": "73fb4e73-97e2-44f6-a880-160933ea881e",
                "displayName": "App SSO in csharp",
                "distributionMethod": "organization"
            }
        },
    // ....
        {
            "id": "Y2I0ZDIxNmYtMWU4Ni00YjhiLTk0ZjAtYzIxM2IyNThkMzc2IyMyNWYzMDBjMS05ZGE2LTRjYTMtYWUwZS1iN2EwZDJkMDQzZGY=",
            "teamsApp": {
                "id": "25f300c1-9da6-4ca3-ae0e-b7a0d2d043df",
                "externalId": "73fb4e73-97e2-44f6-a880-160933ea881e",
                "displayName": "App SSO in csharp",
                "distributionMethod": "sideloaded"
            }
        },
```